# saving uniqid in database & picture folder

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, unique

I'm learning how to rename an uploaded picture (or file) with a unique id so it's not the same as other uploaded files; save it to a database so it can be called as a user's image and save it in the image folder.

My issue, is I have figured out how to rename and save the image with a unique file name but I have no idea how to get that unique filename to save in the database so it calls that exact image. It seems to be saving 'Array' to the database and not the unique filename.

If anyone has any ideas how I can correct this, I would very much appreciate the learning experience haha:

```
<?php 

//This is the directory where images will be saved  

//This gets all the other information from the form 
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$phone=$_POST['phone']; 
$pic=pathinfo($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("businessdb1.db.9878324.hostedresource.com", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("businessdb1") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

//Writes the information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$pic')") ; 

//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
   "avatars/" . uniqid() . '.' . $pic['extension'])) 
{ 

//Tells you if its all ok 
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
} 
else { 

//Gives and error if its not 
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you save AFTER renaming?

Comment: `pathinfo()` returns an array

Comment: Try exploring `$pic` with `var_dump($pic)`, it is an assoc array, that's why you get `Array`. Also this code is not safe as you are inserting user data directly, and to make it even worse you are using deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply save the generated id in a variable and use in in both the `INSERT INTO ...` and the `move_uploaded_file()` call. Something like this:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name']; 
// .... snip ....

// switched to mysqli_ for the example, save the resulting db link (should check for connection errors too)
$db = mysqli_connect( /* login credentials */);
// generate the uniqid and save it to a variable
$file_uniq_id = uniqid();

// then use the generated id here
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
  "avatars/" . $file_uniq_id . '.' . $pic['extension'])) 
{ 

    mysqli_query($db, 'INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (
    '.mysqli_query($db, $name).',
    '.mysqli_query($db, $email).',
    '.mysqli_query($db, $phone).',
    '.mysqli_query($db, $file_uniq_id).')'); // And here, you can add path or extension as you see fit
}
```

There are some non-functionality related problems in your code too:

1. Always escape your query parameters, or you will have [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issues.
2. Stop using the `mysql_*` functions since they are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). The `mysqli_*` family works almost the same.

Comment: What you're saying is making sense to me but I can't seem to get the code to work lol. This mysqli is pretty new to me. I honestly made this harder for myself by wanting a unique id so people wouldn't try to upload a picture with the same extension. I was using this tutorial: http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/Upload_file_sql.htm (changed images folder to avatars due to another tutorial) and it was working just fine uploading, saving in the db and calling the correct image file to display with the user information, but I wanted to add the unique id and that's where it all went awry haha.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no substitute for debugging. Turn on error messages with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and listen to what it can tell you. Also you can place `var_dump()`s to peek into variables so you can see what's (for example, dump the SQL query, the file path you are moving the file to, the return value of the move in the if and so on until you see something out of order. Think of what each should be and then check if it's really gets the values you thought.

Comment: Ok, I will play around with it some more. Thank you for all of your time and help!